# Making Facebook Authorisation with Paw

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, paw-app, paw

I'm trying to reproduce Facebook Login flow for mobile app.
So I have to Login with Facebook, retrieve Facebook profile and then login to my server with Facebook token and profile data.
To Do it I have created two requests:
facebook/me - to get OAuth token and user profile data
myserver/api/facebook_login - to use all this data to login

So I have a number of questions:
- how to get Facebook token ?
I have create "/me" request and put OAuth2 Barier in header:
[image]

So trying to get the token, I'm getting login screen and then the screen like that:
[image]

Looks like the token is filled in the bottom,
But the popup disappeared immediately and error shown:

[image]

The next question is how to get this token as a dynamic variable ?

Comment: Sorry for the super late answer. It sounds like this is because of a UI bug in Paw that makes the "Use Access Token" invisible (because Facebook tokens are very long, the window gets resized too much). We will fix this bug. In the meantime, try moving the window and resize it to make this button appear, and hit the button. I tried it myself, it works then. Your Facebook flow is fine otherwise.